# Why does this CSS-styled button tag work with all browsers except Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

On Firefox, my css-styled buttons (rounded, with tiny icon before the button text) look fine visually, but nothing happens when you click... it's like the `a` tag isn't there?

my html:

```
<button class='xbutton' type='button'>
  <a href="/nextpage"><img alt="Next step" src="/icons/tick.png" /> Next page</a>
</button>
```

my css:

```
button.xbutton{
  padding:5px 10px 5px 7px; 
  line-height:17px; 
}

button.xbutton {
  background: #edeeed url("images/button-background.png") top;
  border: 1px solid #c3c4ba;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

button.xbutton a:link, button.xbutton a:visited{
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

button.xbutton:link, button.xbutton:visited, button.xbutton:hover, button.xbutton:active {
  font-weight: normal;
  background: #edeeed url("images/button-background.png") top;
}


button.xbutton:active {
  background: #eaeaea url("images/button-background-active.png") top;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

Comment: I'd hazard a guess and say firefox is catching the button press event, rather than the hyperlink click event. What are you actually gaining from having the hyperlink inside a button, other than an extra element to style around it?

Comment: your assessment is correct, and I did in fact add a new style to replace it. I was just surprised that it worked fine on everything up until I tried firefox!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's invalid HTML for one thing. It cannot contain an anchor. The button is submitting the form but you are trying to get it to jump to the hyperlink at the same time. You can't do both.

Comment: that explains it, had no idea a button tag could not have a link (it's not being used in a form, it's merely a style for the link so I'll redo it.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `button`. There is no reason why it's needed and it's not valid HTML.

Also, glancing at your CSS, `:link` and `:visited` only apply to anchors, not to buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML4 DTD clearly indicates that you should not include links inside the button tag (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON) :

```
<!ELEMENT BUTTON - -
 (%flow;)* -(A|%formctrl;|FORM|FIELDSET)
 -- push button -->
```

You should either try styling your links to get the look that you want (try applying your current styles to your link, it looked OK on jsFiddle), or attach an event handler via JavaScript to handle the click on your button.